# Memory issue in iOS Keyboard Extension

Tags: ios, swift, memory, keyboard

I am using the following code in an iOS keyboard extension.

```
 var wordDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
 wordDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("dictionary", ofType: "plist")!)!

 var wordDictionary1 = NSMutableDictionary()       
 wordDictionary1 = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("dictionary1", ofType: "plist")!)!
```

Here the size of `dictionary.plist` is 3.5MB and the size of `dictionary1.plist` is 44.8MB.
The `dictionary.plist` file includes about 10,000 key/value pairs; the `dictionary1.plist` file includes about 200,000.

The second line works perfectly.
In my opinion, OS of real iPhone device cannot alloc 30MB+ memory in a keyboard extension; or rather, a keyboard extension cannot use 30MB+ memory.
But the fourth line causes a crash. The log says:

> Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue. Program ended with exit code: 0

I tested this on an iPhone 6s, and with Xcode versions 8.0 and 7.3 on Mac OS Sierra 10.12 and 10.11.4. The above code works perfectly on the simulator.

How can I avoid this crash?

Comment: I think you might have answered your own question `In my opinion, OS of real iPhone device cannot alloc 30MB+ memory for keyboard extension`. The problem is that keyboards are supposed to be fast and lightweight, if a keyboard is suddenly using more memory than an app you will probably find that it's slow and no-one will use it (which is why Apple added a memory limit). I would suggest that you look at CoreData to store all of your data as that will only load into memory whats needed and not everything like you are trying to do with your .plist solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can split this big file into two or more. And for example if you need to search through these files you load these files alternately.

Also if it's sorted alphabetically then you can split it by letters like: `dictionary-A-H.plist` and `dictionary-I-Z.plist`.